# compare string in array php

Tags: php

In php

```
a[]={'jeans','nishalli','baseses.','hude','htad','dfsdf','dfee','ddddd','ddfsa','fsadfa','dsfdasf','dfasdf','dsfdasf','dfdasf'};
```

i want to search the keyword = baseses

how to i can get the word baseses.

please help me.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**in_array**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
if (in_array('baseses', $a))
{
   echo 'So you found me !!';
}
```

Or you can even use **[array_search](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)**

Answer (score 0):

Try in_array()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: Doesn't return key, just a true/false if in array.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you'd use [array_search()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php), but that doesn't look like PHP.