# Use "billing company name", as Display name publicly in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've written a line of code to put in my functions.php file in my theme. I'm trying to target only the user role - Employer to set the Billing Company Name field as Display name publicly as. But its not applying the information

```
function set_default_display_name( $user_id ) {
  $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
  $name = sprintf( '%s %s', $user->first_name, $user->last_name );
  $user_roles = $user->roles;
  $business_role = "Employer";
  $user_company = $user['billing_company'][0];

  if ( $user_roles == $business_role ) {
  $args = array(
    'ID'           => $user_id,
    'display_name' => $user_company,
    'nickname'     => $user_company
  );
  wp_update_user( $args );
  }
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'set_default_display_name' );
```

Comment: Is `$user_roles` a string?  The name of the variable leads me to believe that it may be an array or object.  Which would explain why the `if ( $user_roles == $business_role )` condition is not being met.

Comment: Indeed, it seems that the [roles property](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/#public-properties) is an array.  That means you probably want to be using [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: @PatrickQ I'm trying to use `$user_roles = $user->roles;` to pull the user's role and assign it to the variable. Are you saying that I need to write that set variable as an array?

Comment: I'm saying that you're currently trying to compare an array (`$user_roles`) with a string (`$bussiness_role`) by using `==`.  You can't do that (well, I mean, technically you _can_, but it won't do anything useful).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [compare string in array php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278957/compare-string-in-array-php)